# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k}\binom{n}{k} = 1+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, binomial-coefficients

For the past 30 minutes I've tried to solve this identity but with no luck.
I've tried with math induction,perturbation method and to write the sum and find some simetry but non of them worked.
Could someone please help me?
Thank you.

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k}\binom{n}{k} = 1+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation ; http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484425/prove-by-induction-sum-limits-k-1n-1k1n-choose-k-frac1k-1-f