# Asymptotic expansion of $\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} (-1)^k \frac 1 {1-x^k} $

Tags: limits, summation, asymptotics

I'm trying to find the limit (and asymptotic expansion as $n\to\infty $) of
$$\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} (-1)^k \frac 1 {1-x^k} $$

for $0<x<1$.

So far, I have no idea...

I found this question when dealing with the expected value of $\max (X_1, \dots X_n)$ when $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are geometric random variables with same success probability $p$...

Thus, the expected value is this sum for $x=1-p$ (in absolute value)...

Could you help me please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asymptotic expansion when $x\to 1$?

Comment: For $n\to\infty$ see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2923416).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Your suggestion of writing $S$ as $\sum_{i \geq 0} ((1 - x^i)^n - 1)$ is sufficient to get the $\ln n/\ln x + O(1)$ estimate for fixed $x$ and $n \to \infty$, since the difference between $S$ and
$$\int_0^\infty ((1 - x^i)^n - 1) di =
\frac {H_n} {\ln x}$$
is bounded.

Comment: I think this is a very interesting question, but the format is that of a PSQ, and so it may get closed and even deleted, and those who answer may get penalized. Please try to add some [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960); where you found the question, if it is from a class or textbook, what are some of the other topics being discussed at the time, etc.

Comment: @metamorphy I was expecting a simpler solution than yours and I don't know the tools you are using... So I consider it as incomplete regarding the context of this question... (added context)...

Comment: @Maxim: Since the integrand is monotonically increasing (from $-1$ to $0$), the integral is less than $1$ above the sum. This is the "$-[0,1]$" after the integral in my answer.

Comment: The OP added clarification and some context after being requested. I don't think it deserves to be closed for lack of context.

Comment: @BastienTourand: even though you have added where this question came from, perhaps you could expand on the parts alluded to, but elided by the ellipses (the parts that follow the "..."s).

Comment: Have you read this ? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26214/312

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A First Approach**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\frac1{1-x^k}
&=-1+\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\frac{x^k}{1-x^k}\tag1\\
&=-1+\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\sum_{j=1}^\infty x^{jk}\tag2\\
&=-1+\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}x^{jk}\tag3\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(\left(1-x^j\right)^n-1\right)\tag4\\
&\sim\int_0^\infty\left(1-\left(1-n^{-t}\right)^n\right)\frac{\log(n)}{\log(x)}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $\frac1{1-x^k}=1+\frac{x^k}{1-x^k}$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k=-1$
$(2)$: $\frac{x^k}{1-x^k}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty x^{jk}$
$(3)$: change order of summation
$(4)$: apply the binomial theorem, then note that the $j=0$ term is $-1$
$(5)$: approximate the sum with an integral using $j=-t\frac{\log(n)}{\log(x)}$

Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty\left(1-\left(1-n^{-t}\right)^n\right)\,\mathrm{d}t=1$, the sum should be asymptotic to $\frac{\log(n)}{\log(x)}$.

---

**A Second Approach**

The sum in $(4)$ can also be approximated by
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(\left(1-x^j\right)^n-1\right)
&=\int_0^\infty\left(\left(1-x^t\right)^n-1\right)\mathrm{d}t-[0,1]_\#\tag6\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\int_0^\infty e^{kt\log(x)}\mathrm{d}t-[0,1]_\#\tag7\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}\frac1{k\log(x)}-[0,1]_\#\tag8\\
&=\frac{H_n}{\log(x)}-[0,1]_\#\tag9
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(6)$: overestimate the sum with an integral
$\phantom{\text{(6):}}$ the variation of the integrand is equal to $1$
$\phantom{\text{(6):}}$ $[0,1]_\#$ represents a real number between $0$ and $1$
$(7)$: $x^t=e^{t\log(x)}$, then apply the binomial theorem
$(8)$: evaluate the integral
$(9)$: apply [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1484460)

Comment: Incredibly simple (after reading it !) ! For the case $n= 10$ and $x=0.9$,  $\frac{H_n}{\log (x)}\sim -27.7995$ for an exact value  $-28.2995$ ! More than impressive. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: If we use $0.5$ for the $[0,1]$, it is pretty close (not only in your example).

Comment: I was just about to make the same comment.  In French, we use to say something like *"great minds meet"* This is fully true except that I am not one. By the way, I made my expansion using unsigned Stirling numbers. I suppose that you noticed what is the first coefficient. Cheers and thanks again :-)

Answer (score 4):

Not a complete answer, but an idea of where to look and some lower bounds.

Let $$p_k(x)=\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}=1+x+\dots+x^{k-1}$$

Then:

$$\frac{1}{1-x^k}=\frac{1}{k(1-x)}+\frac{(k-1)+(k-2)x+\cdots+x^{k-2}}{kp(x)}$$

Also, $$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}k\frac1k&=\int_0^1\frac{(1-t)^n-1}{t}\,dt\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{t^n-1}{1-t}\,dt\\
&=-\int_0^1(1+t+t^2+\cdots+t^{k-1})\,dt\\
&=-\left(1+\frac12+\cdots+\frac{1}{n-1}\right) =-H_{n-1}
\end{align}$$

So if $f_n(x)$ is your term, then $$f_n(x)=\frac{-H_n}{1-x}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k\binom nkq_k(x)$$

When $$q_k(x)=\frac{(k-1)+(k-2)x+\cdots+x^{k-2}}{kp(x)}$$

Notice that $$q_k(x)=\frac{x^{k-2}p_k’(1/x)}{kx^{k-1}p_k(1/x)}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{p_k’(1/x)}{kp_k(1/x)}$$

For any polynomial $p$ with no repeating roots, $$\frac{p’(y)}{p(y)}=\sum_j \frac{1}{y-r_i}$$ where the $r_i$ are the roots of the polynomial.

So:

$$\begin{align}q_k(x)&=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{1-xe^{2\pi ij/k}}\\
&= \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{1-xe^{-2\pi ij/k}}{1+x^2-2x\cos(2\pi ij/k)}\\
&=\frac1k\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{1-x\cos(2\pi j/k)} {1+x^2-2x\cos(2\pi j/k)}
\end{align}
$$

The last step because we know the imaginary values cancel.

Now:

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{1+x^2-2x\cos\theta}&=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2x\cos\theta}{1+x^2}\right)^p\\
&\geq\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{2x\cos\theta}{(1+x^2)^2}
\end{align}$$

So:

$$\frac{1-x\cos\theta}{1+x^2-2x\cos\theta}\geq\\ \frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{2x\cos\theta}{(1+x^2)^2} -\frac{x(1+x^2)\cos\theta}{(1+x^2)^2}-\frac{2x^2\cos^2\theta}{(1+x^2)^2}\\=
\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{x(1-x^2)\cos\theta}{(1+x^2)^2}-\frac{2x^2\cos^2\theta}{(1+x^2)^2}
$$

Now:

$$\sum_{j=1}^k\cos(2\pi j/k)=-1$$

and $$\sum_{j=1}^k\cos^{2}(2\pi j/k)=\frac k2$$

So: $$q_k(x)\geq\frac1k\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{x(1-x^2)}{(1+x^2)^2}-\frac{kx^2} {(1+x^2)^2}\right)$$

Comment: How would compare our answers ? I also have bounds. Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: Is it sufficient to get $\ln n/\ln x + O(1)$ as @Maxim suggested above ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the asymptotics of
$$f_n=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k\,{n \choose k} \, \frac 1 {1-x^k}$$ for $x \to 1$,we have (from an old work of mine)
$$f_n=\frac{\left|S_{n+1}^{(2)}\right|}{n!}\frac 1{(x-1)}+\frac{\left|S_{n+1}^{(2)}\right|-\left|S_{n+1}^{(1)}\right|}{2 \,n!}-\frac{\left|S_{n+1}^{(2)}\right| }{12\, n!}(x-1)+\frac{\left|S_{n+1}^{(2)}\right| }{24\, n!}(x-1)^2+O((x-1)^3)$$ where appear unsigned  Stirling numbers of the first and second kinds.

Trying for $n=10$ and $x=\frac 9{10}$, the exact result is
$$-\frac{22954528746372225790890814301786200}{811128802013725681512205937948047}$$ while the above truncated expansion gives
$$-\frac{19017311}{672000}$$

The absolute difference between these two numbers is $8.32\times 10^{-5}$.

**Question**

The next term of the expansion is
$$-\frac{c_n}{720 \,n!} (x-1)^3$$ where the $c_n$'s form the sequence
$$\{45,245,950,5206,33516,248292,2082096,19504944,201944160,\cdots\}$$ What could they be ?