# How Can I Compute $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1} \binom{n}{k} \dfrac{1}{k}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

Proof

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1} \binom{n}{k} \dfrac{1}{k} = 1 + \dfrac{1}{2} + \dots + \dfrac{1}{n}
$$

---

This might be a silly question asked by someone else but I cannot find it right now.

I tried to verify this formula in Mathematica, and I am sure that this statement is correct.

The first approach I tried is to use generating functions and the binomial theorem, where I got

$$
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}(-\sum _{k=1}^n \dfrac{x^k}{k} \binom{n}{k}) = -\sum _{k=1}^n x^{k-1} \binom{n}{k} = \dfrac{1-(x+1)^n}{x}
$$

But I am having difficulties integrating the RHS: even Mathematica gives a function that includes "HypergeometricPFQ" which is not elementary.

The second approach I tried is to use induction. But I find it really difficult to use the inductive hypothesis.

Is there a better way to solve this question? Or where can I find any resources?

But

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove by induction: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}{n\choose k}\frac{1}{k}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484425/prove-by-induction-sum-limits-k-1n-1k1n-choose-k-frac1k-1-f) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En(-1)%5E%7Bk-1%7D%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bk%7D%3D1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%2B%5Cldots%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%24&p=1). Note there also quite a few other duplicates (with all of the following questions actually ...

Comment: Yes. I am sorry for posting duplicate questions. Thank you for helping!

Comment: (cont.) being closed as duplicates of other questions) here, e.g., [Prove by induction $\sum _{i=1}^n\left(-1\right)^{i+1}\:\binom{n}{i}\:\frac{1}{i}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}$](/q/1490571), [Proof of a sum with binomial coefficients $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1}{\binom nk}\frac{1}{k} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \ldots +\frac{1}{n}$](/q/1498860), [Proof for any positive integer n the following equality hold](/q/3481345), [Find the value of $\sum_0^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k \frac{1}{k+1}$](/q/1490583), ...

Comment: (cont.) [Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k}\binom{n}{k} = 1+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{n}$](/q/2014841), etc. Finally, you're welcome for the help, and also welcome to Math SE.